# Why React Router only works with stateless component?

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying the simplest code to understand the React Router. 
I brought the example of the site: "https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic" and only changed one thing, the component 'About'.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Route,
Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

const BasicExample = () => (
<Router>
    <div>
    <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
    </ul>

    <hr/>

    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/about/:aaa" component={About}/>
    <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
    </div>
</Router>
)

const Home = () => (
<div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
</div>
)


class About extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>About</h2>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
<div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>
        Rendering with React
        </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>
        Components
        </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
        Props v. State
        </Link>
    </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic}/>
    <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => (
    <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
    )}/>
</div>
)

console.log('Topics', Topics);

const Topic = ({ match }) => (
<div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
</div>
)

export default BasicExample

ReactDOM.render(<BasicExample />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

If i use:

```
class About extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>About</h2>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

React-router do not show this component. and why i want to use this? because with this i can use State.

Now i'm reading this article: https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc

Maybe i will find the answer there. then i will come and edit...

Comment: What does "does not work" exactly mean? Does it literally return "I do not work" string?

Comment: You are commenting out this component.  What are you expecting now?

Comment: Remove `/:aaa` from `<Route path="/about/:aaa" component={About}/>`

Comment: I removed The coment...

Comment: Kyle, how can i do this passing The variable :aaa?

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood. If you're trying to get the route params, pass `match` to your component and use `props.match.params.aaa`. In a class it would be `this.props.match.params.aaa`. Or `match.params.aaa` with es6 destructuring.

Comment: All i needed to know came from the sugestion to change que name of the question = "stateless components", my question is: why react router only works with Stateless components? now i'm reading this article that is helping a lot, https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc